# Xamarin App crashes on Reopen NullReference

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, crash, activity-lifecycle

I have an app on Xamarin, it works fine, if I press back button, to move to main menu it hides in app stack, so when I open it back from app stack it suddenly crashes with NullReference

```
06-10 15:59:57.363 I/MonoDroid(14891): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-10 15:59:57.363 I/MonoDroid(14891): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
06-10 15:59:57.363 I/MonoDroid(14891): at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.OnPrepareOptionsMenu (Android.Views.IMenu) <IL 0x00007, 0x00050>
06-10 15:59:57.363 I/MonoDroid(14891): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnPrepareOptionsMenu_Landroid_view_Menu_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4151
06-10 15:59:57.363 I/MonoDroid(14891): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.87f976f0-8c0f-4463-92f4-c8ed92b6336d (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x0004b>
06-10 15:59:57.383 D/AndroidRuntime(14891): Shutting down VM
06-10 15:59:57.383 W/dalvikvm(14891): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b66c08)
An unhandled exception occured.
```

Any ideas will be helpful, stuck with it for too long

my main activity code:
http://pastebin.com/d9G77MJg

Comment: Can you post the code of your activity ? Also are you using XamarinForms or just Xamarin ?

Comment: Are you trying to hide your ActionBar/Toolbar in Xamarin.Forms? If so you can't have menu items. Would need to see you Activity.cs are you trying to inflate a menu in there?

Comment: @JamesMontemagno no, I'm not doing that

Comment: @Greag.Deay do you have this sample somewhere I can test? james@xamarin.com if you want to email me directly. I would need to see your pages. Some other framework you are using might be trying to do something, or perhaps there is something on one of the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured out this issue. The problem was with a 3rd party library that isn't officially supported (XLabs). They have their own dependency service and Greag was re-registering things causing an exception that was being gobbled up so the LoadApplication would never be loaded.

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/131787
Adam Kemp also have a point of view on this problem, it is a bug related to Xamarin, that App needs to relaunch